# Replacing Vauxhall Corsa C (2002) rear fog light

Tags: electrical, body, replace, lights, vauxhall

I need to replace the right rear fog light in a 2002 Vauxhall Corsa C; not just the bulb but the whole unit. I'm looking for instructions on how to replace the lamp preferably without removing the rear bumper (if at all possible).

For whatever reason, this isn't covered by the Haynes manual for this car! Front fog-lights are, but the only mention of rear fog-lights is in a list of wattages for relevant external bulbs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've search for an online procedure, without success. But looking how the lamp is built, it's looks like you have 2 bracket on each side of the lamp. Unless you can access it from behind the bumper (which I doubt), you'll need to remove the bumper. If unsure, maybe take some pictures of your setup and update your original post with them.

Here's one image of that fog lamp:

[image]

Comment: Yep, had to remove the bumper. But it was easier than expected. There's some clips underneath the bumper and screws under the rear wheel arches.